# microsoft365r email "send as"

Tags: r, email, microsoft365r

I would like to send emails using "send as". Is that possible in microsoft365r? If so, how?

In the outlook app, I can select "new mail", "from" and change the user. Is it possible to change the user using microsoft365r?

ex. my_outlook$create_email("here are words in the body", subject = "subject line info", **send_as = "A. Name**, to = "receive@address")

I haven't tried anything, as I can't find a function that does what I would like.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.